# How to parse a string containing "trans" tags as a template in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, translation

I'm trying to create a dynamic template from a string (I know, dynamic template is an oxymoron) but I'm having trouble with `{% trans %}` tags.  If the string contains:

```
{% trans %}Hello{% endtrans %}
```

then when I do this:

```
    context = RequestContext(request, data)
    template = Template(text)
    out_text = template.render(context)
```

I get an internal server error.  I've tried adding `{% load i18n %}` to the string, but that doesn't help.  What do I need to do to make the string translatable?  It is working fine with html files, but I can't get it to work with strings.  If I take the `trans` tags out, it parses the template string fine.

Comment: You first need to know where it tanked. Try setting `DEBUG=true` in `settings.py` and then running this with the development server. The stack trace + ability to examine local variables normally leads to quick enlightenment.

Comment: Thanks, being able to debug will help alot!  But all it says is: `Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError`
`Exception Value: Invalid block tag: 'trans'`

Comment: Ah, sorry, with `{% load i18n %}` first, it says: `Exception Value: Searching for value. Expected another value but found end of string: trans`

Comment: That last message sounds interesting. So now we go look at the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/internationalization/#trans-template-tag) and lo and behold, you are using the `trans` tag as if it were the `blocktrans` tag.

Comment: Ah, I see, I am using jinja2 tags... how to render the text using jinja2?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it might be described on this page: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#basics. Remember, RTFM is not just a four-letter acronym, It's The Law®. ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I think my question is a bit more complication than I thought... and believe me, I've RTFM and the FM is pretty opaque.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this template is loaded and parsed by Jinja instead of Django?

I am using Jinja2 via Coffin in my Django project, and error you have always results when template is loaded without Coffin participation.

Check which loader found template first. Was it Coffin/Jinja one or Django loader? If it was found by Django, it will be parsed by Django, which doesnt know how to handle {% trans %}{% endtrans %} block.